# Regex in conditional or with exact number of digits

Tags: php, regex

I've been struggling to achieve regex with the operator or.

For example
Having the following chain:
Allowed numbers: 1, 2, 5, 6, 20

"/path/item/1"

"/path/item/2"

"/path/item/5"
etc

The regex that I have been testing is:

```
"/\/path\/item\/(1|2|5|6|20)/"
```

What I want is for regex to return true only if it is 1 or 2 or 5 or 6, etc.

But for the example of the number 20, the regex returns true for 2 and not for 20.

How can I validate each value independently, that is to say that it is only true if it is 2 and not 20. But true when it is 20 but not 2.

How would the regex be to implement this validation?
[Ejemplo](https://regex101.com/r/YDUgM6/2)

Comment: Use this pattern: `"^/\/path\/item\/(?:20|[1256])/$"` i.e. `20` before matching `2` in alternation.

Comment: I don't get it.  Your pattern matches for `2` or `20`, so why does a perceived order of matching matter?

Comment: the order does not matter, the value 20 is by way of example, since the values can be changed dynamically.

Comment: Order matters when you don't use anchors or word boundary. See this example: https://regex101.com/r/YDUgM6/3 However if you use anchors as suggested then order won't matter.

Comment: Either put the `20` before the `2` (i.e., [`\/path\/item\/(1|20|5|6|2)`](https://regex101.com/r/LphXCr/1)) or make the `0` optional (i.e., [`\/path\/item\/(1|20?|5|6|)`](https://regex101.com/r/LphXCr/2)).

Comment: If you don't want to capture the digits you could use a non capturing group as well. If you change the delimiter you might use `~/path/item/(?:[1256]|20)\b~`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to restrict the search such that the matched digits bring you to the end of the string:

`"/\/path\/item\/(1|2|5|6|20)$/"`

This will mean that the digits must exactly match, and does not involve any re-ordering of the permitted values in your regex.

Demonstrated [here](https://regex101.com/r/YDUgM6/4)

Answer (score 1):

The key is to add the large numbers first in the capturing or non-capturing group, such as:

```
^\/path\/item\/(20|1|2|5|6)$
```

or

```
^\/path\/item\/(?:20|1|2|5|6)$
```

or

```
\/path\/item\/(?:20|1|2|5|6)
```

#### Test

```
$re = '/^\/path\/item\/(20|1|2|5|6)$/s';
$str = '/path/item/20';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

var_dump($matches);
```

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/Tltd0r/1/), if you wish to explore further or modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/Tltd0r/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs step by step, if you like.

Answer (score 0):

Problem with your code was, whenever you sent `20` to match, `2` was matched first and was ignored as there also was `0` following. This can be resolved by giving `20` first, like this:

```
\/path\/item\/(20|1|2|5|6)\/
```

View Here: https://regex101.com/r/aJf1Q8/1